# iOS: not working with pinned cert mode in cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Tags: ios, cordova, vue.js, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

I am using Cordova-plugin-advanced-http v2.0.1 plugin for "pinned" certificate mode for enabling SSL pinning.
The same code is working in android but not working in iOS for Cordova application.

I have used one certificate which is not valid so it is giving an error in Android but not in iOS.

```
mounted() {
  cordova.plugin.http.setSSLCertMode('pinned', function() {
    console.log('success....!');
  }, function() {
    console.log('error....');
  });
```

}

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar issues with ionic3 app, have you got any solution for the same? Also can you provide steps how to use it for Android?

Comment: For android, you have to put your certificates in www folder and then just paste the code for pinning. It is working for me.